# Split a log file into blocks delimited by a regex

Tags: java, regex, file, java.util.scanner

What's the most efficient way to split a log-file into blocks delimited by a regex.

Log file contains several requests/blocks (the line count for each block is variable - depends on the method, etc)

The only way to identify that a previous request/block finished is by EOF or start of another one: with a particular message.

I want, using the regex for this particular message to split the entire file and get the blocks in order to parse each of them individually.

Structure of the log file:

```
START_A_NEW_BLOCK_1:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit



Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit



START_A_NEW_BLOCK_2:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] res = str.split( "START_A_NEW_BLOCK_\d+:" );
```